# WPF ¿Diferencias entre Grid y StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf

¿Que diferencias existen entre estos dos contenedores?
Leo manuales pero no logro ver cuando utilizar unos y otros...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tomando una simple imagen de google de entorno grafico de un software, ¿Se supone que las Grid son las marcadas en amarillo y los stack panel se usan para ir colocando contenedores uno debajo de otro?

Comment: Que manuales? porque la diferencia es contundente.. uno es una grilla y el otro una pila... Podrias ser mas preciso sobre porque no ves que son diferentes?

Comment: Por ejemplo, si yo creo una Gril con un botón en su interior, después, debajo del código de esa Gril creo otra Gril exactamente igual, y después otra... ¿No se consigue así una pila?
Se que estoy totalmente equivocado en mi teoría pero no logro ver cuando hay que usar un control y otro. 
Hasta donde se, los dos permiten alojar multitud de controles dentro de ellos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack te organiza los elementos en una pila, uno de bajo del otro:

```
<StakPanel>
  <TextBlock>Elemento 1</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock>Elemento 2</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Esto dara como resultado por ejemplo:

```
Elemento 1
Elemento 2
```

Mientras que el `Grid` organiza los elementos por cuadrillas:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
  <Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Elemento 1" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Elemento 2" />
</Grid>
```

Esto lo que hace es que crea 2 columnas con un ancho de 100 pixeles la primera y la segunda de 50 y una sola fila con el tamaño que los elementos ocupan. Fíjate que a los elementos hay que especificarle la columna en la cual sera situada utilizando `Grid.Column`. A los grid tambien puedes pecificarle el tamaño de altura utilizando Grid.RowDefinition:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
  <Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="100" />
     <RowDefinition Height="100" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Elemento 1" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="Elemento 2" />
</Grid>
```

Ahora en este ejemplo se agregaron filas, ambas con un alto de 100 pixeles.

A las columnas tambien se les puede asignar tamaño por porcentaje utilizando el asterisco `*`. Por ejemplo digamos que queremos el ancho para el primer elemento sea un 70% del contendor y el segundo sea un 30% que juntos harian un 100%. Esto quedaria asi:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*70" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*10" />
  <Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="100" />
     <RowDefinition Height="100" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Elemento 1" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="Elemento 2" />
</Grid>
```

*70 significa que tome el 70% y *30 que tome el 30 porcierto.

En resumen, Grid es mucho mas flexible que StackPanel solo que lleva un poco mas de configuracion.

Comment: Gracias, es una gran explicación pero... ¿Sirven para lo mismo? Dejando aparte que el Grid es mas flexible y potente, claro esta...

Comment: El concepto de ambos es dar estructura a los elementos dentro de ellos. Asi que si te refieres a eso, si, sirven para lo mismo: ORGANIZAR. Ahora bien, cada cual tiene su propia manera de organizar.

Comment: Ojo! StackPanel no solo es para apilar "una cosa bajo otra" sino también "al lado de otra", para ello es la propiedad "Orientation"